# UIWebView cannot be linked to my outlet !

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview, interface-builder

I'm modifying my program and I cannot link the Outlet to the xib.

The code below is from the header file :

```
@interface GraphNavController : UINavigationController {
     ...
     IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
     ...
}
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
...
```

and in the .m file :

```
@implementation GraphNavController

@synthetize webView;
```

This image is captured when I tried to assign the outlet to the webview :

[image: caption of the problem]

If you have any suggestion to solve my problem, you're reaaaaaaaly welcome :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on "File's Owner" to see the outlet and then you can connect it.
Also, make sure that your File Owner class is `GraphNavController`

Comment: I only see the delegate, and when I try to link them, I only see odelegate again, without my UIWebView outlet...

Comment: You will see delegate when you right click on WebView. I am asking you to right click over "File's Owner" in your XIB file.

Comment: @Imran : Thanks . Yes, I did it : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/684690Capturedcran20110630114748.png

Comment: And, are you sure that the class associated with File's Owner is your GraphNavController? You can see it by selecting File's Owner from your xib first and then switching to Identity Inspector.

Comment: @Imran : OK, apparently, it's a UIApplication if I understood what I've to do : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/608040Capturedcran20110630115708.png

Comment: Ok, so in your xib file you will see a 'ViewController' just above your WebView. That is the view controller that handles your web view. So, all you need to do is, to select this view controller and in the Identity Inspector choose 'GraphNavController' as its class. Then, try to connect the outlet again.

Comment: @Imran : OK, thanks. Now I have errors with the gestures... huhum

Comment: "incompatible types in assignment" for the line gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

Comment: @Imran : haha indeed I have a screen : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/709898Capturedcran20110630124433.png . It ran... before

Comment: @Imran : I've hidden the code implemented for the gestures to show if the webpage is running but the program bug when he arrives to a "self" ... and this is the same issue for the gestures (it was the "self" that make the app bug...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `IBOutlet` is not shown and thats why you are not able to connect it.
Try this one:
Go to Interface Builder, File >> Read Class File
The select the file in which you have create the IBOutlets

Hope this will help....